# Boxplots based on TRUE/FALSE variable columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, reshape2

I have data that can be roughly replicated using

```
n = 10
df = data.frame(
  val= rnorm(n), 
  var1 = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5),
  var2 = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5),
  var3 = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5))
```

How can I plot this on a boxplot? What I'm looking for will have `var1`, `var2` and `var3` on the x-axis and `val` on the y-axis i.e. the box-and-whisker for `var1` will contain only observations that have a 1 in the `var1` column.

I've tried

```
df2 = melt(df, id.vars = c('val'), 
           variable.name ='vars', value.name = "include")

ggplot(df2, aes(x = include, y = val)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = vars)
```

but when I plot this I get 3 boxplots that look exactly the same.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In base R we can do

```
boxplot(sapply(df[-1], function(x) df$val[as.logical(x)]))
```

[image]

Or using `ggplot2`

```
df.r <- do.call(rbind, lapply(names(df)[-1], function(x) 
  data.frame(x, y=df$val[as.logical(df[,x])])))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df.r, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=y))
```

[image]

---

*Data*

```
df <- structure(list(val = c(1.37095844714667, -0.564698171396089, 
0.363128411337339, 0.63286260496104, 0.404268323140999, -0.106124516091484, 
1.51152199743894, -0.0946590384130976, 2.01842371387704, -0.062714099052421
), var1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), var2 = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), var3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The boxes are all the same because the graph is not taking into consideration the `include` vector. This is handled by the `subset` instruction in `ggplot`'s `data` argument.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(subset(df2, include != 0), aes(vars, val)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

**Data creation code.**

I am reposting the data creation code setting the RNG seed.

```
set.seed(1234)
n = 10
df = data.frame(
  val= rnorm(n), 
  var1 = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5),
  var2 = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5),
  var3 = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5))
df

df2 <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = c('val'), 
           variable.name ='vars', value.name = "include")
```